# P4 Sync command with local paths?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to call a p4 sync command on a local path from within python.

```
P4dir = "D:/Perforce/Project/*"
subprocess.call("p4 sync " + P4dir)
```

This fails with a non-existing directory error.
However, if i call the sever path, it works fine:

```
P4dir = "//depot/Project/*"
subprocess.call("p4 sync " + P4dir)
```

This is probably extremely simple and I'm a bit embarassed i have to ask, but the documentation for P4 commandline arguments is lacking a lot.

So is there perhaps a way to translate a local path, should be simple by just checking the mappings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `p4 where` to convert local paths. Example:

```
$ p4 where /home/user/perforce/project
//depot/project //the_workspace/project /home/user/perforce/project
```

I tired this on a Linux box so the local path is *nix style, but it should work on Windows as well. `p4 where` also works with relative paths like `./some_folder` which is very handy.

Comment: Thanks! I had to add some extra code to be able to read back output from a commandline argument in python, i'll add that in here as well:
'    P4dir = "D:/Perforce/Project"
    output,error = subprocess.Popen(["p4", "where", P4dir],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    subprocess.call("p4 update " + output.split(" ")[0] + "/*")'

Comment: Woe unto you if you happen to have spaces in your paths, though.  Since you're already using python, you might want to use `p4 -G where PATH` instead (or use the Perforce python API).

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting P4 does not realise that you intended to pass it a local path.  (In Unix sense, it does not look like one.)  Have you tried executing `p4 sync *` with `D:/Perforce/Project` its current directory?

On a different tack, if your P4 binaries have been built with Cygwin, you may be able to specify the path as `/cygdrive/d/Perforce/Project`.